# Why won't my while loop initiate in this c code?

Tags: c

I'm new at programming in c but I just don't understand why this code won't run properly after compiling. For now, I just want it to take numbers between 10 and 100 without errors. Then later I'll add return 1 for errors and 0 for success.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int intGet(int, int);
int error();

int main(void)
{
    int Min, Max, UserIn;
    Min = 10;
    Max = 100;

    printf("Enter a number in between [10 -­100]: \n");
    scanf("%d", &UserIn);
    printf("Read %d\n", UserIn);

    while (UserIn < Min && UserIn > Max)
    {
        printf("Invalid \n");
        scanf("%d", &UserIn);
    }
    /* What I did to fix
      while ((UserIn > Min) || (UserIn < Max)){
         printf("Enter a number in between [10 -­100]: \n");
         scanf("%d",&UserIn);       
         printf("Read %d\n",UserIn);

       while ((UserIn < Min) || (UserIn > Max)){
         printf("Invalid \n");
         scanf("%d", &UserIn);
          printf("Read %d\n", UserIn);


       }
      }*/

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int intGet(int min, int max)
{

}

int error()
{

}
```

Comment: A number can never be both less than the min **and** greater than the max, unless min is greater than max. Try OR (`||`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help you debug this, try this code:

```
while ((UserIn < Min) || (UserIn > Max))
{
    printf("Invalid \n");
    scanf("%d", &UserIn);
    printf("Read %d\n", UserIn);
}
```

Also, this while loop will only run if the first inputted value for Userin was < 10 or > 100.

Comment: Why doesn't it keep looping and asking for more inputs if the condition between 10-100 are met?

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi, because if UserIn is <= min and <= max then the while condition is FALSE.  if you want to keep reading when UserIn is between min and max then code: `while ((UserIn >= min) && (UserIn <= max))`  While loops only while the test is TRUE.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I used your code to for the program to check both if both condition are true by putting it inside the first while loop. It was just a stupid logic error.

Answer (score 2):

`while (UserIn < Min && UserIn > Max)`

`userIn` can never meet both conditions. Change it to:

`whihe (userIn < Min || userIn > Max)`

Comment: Are you entering a number outside your range (e.g. < 0 or > 100)?

Comment: No, I am not. It doesn't work either ways. I'm experimenting with do while to see if anything changes

Comment: Considered using the debugger?

Comment: I just tested your code. The program works fine for all number within the range [1-100] inclusive, and by works fine I mean it displays the 'invalid' error message.

Comment: I do not know anything about the C's debugger. I've only used such thing in java.

Comment: Yes it does print invalid forever which isn't desirable but worst it doesn't continue to ask when the range is met

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi - Perhaps it is a good idea to start learning. In SW engineering it is one of the most useful tools.

Comment: True, I just thought this would be a small thing for a pro c programmer to solve without the debugger because it's more useful for memory leaks in heap and bigger problems. Basically, I just want it to take new inputs between ranges 10-100

Comment: I've experimented with do while but I'm having trouble with: 01_input.c: In function ‘main’:
01_input.c:59:2: error: expected ‘while’ before ‘return’

  




                   ...................................................................  do{
printf("Enter a number in between [10 -­100]: \n");
scanf("%d",&UserIn);
printf("Read %d\n",UserIn);
while  (UserIn>Min||UserIn<Max);

if (UserIn<Min || UserIn >Max){
 printf("Invalid");
 }
}

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi - As you are trying to learn C, (just like Java), you need to learn the debugger - they go hand-in-hand.

Comment: Thanks everyone, you guys were mostly helpful. Now.. I'll go bang my head until a solution comes out.

Comment: are you assuming all numbers between and including 10 and 100 are valid. and everything outside that range is invalid? If that's what you're trying to achieve, then you'll need to negate both conditions and turn the `or` into `and`. demorgan's law, if you've ever heard of it

Comment: Ok I fixed it for now... by adding another while loop withing the first while loop. I'll what I did in the main post.

Comment: @Ed Heal - It was just a dumb logic error. I doubt that the Debugger would find it.

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi - Yes it would - you would see that the execution is going somewhere where you are not expecting it to go.

Answer (score 1):

You do realise that `scanf` does return a value? See http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf

If it does not return 1 then you need to "eat" some input.

Better to read in a string and parse that.

Also

```
while (UserIn < Min && UserIn > Max)
```

should be

```
while (UserIn < Min || UserIn > Max)
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
while (UserIn<Min && UserIn>Max){
```

with:

```
while (UserIn<Min || UserIn>Max){
```

also you can replace your while loop with do ... while. then you will not have double scanf